# "Incorrect syntax near 'maxprice'."

Tags: sql

Having some context for the problem in question may help a lot.

> Create a query that will show all clothing that is medium sized and has a max price of $10 or less. Further include a column that will show a 30% marked down on the max price. Rename your columns as you see below and using the round function round the discounted price to two decimals. The results you see show the correct rows that need to be displayed but not the correct spacing. My output is smaller so that it will display on a single screen.  You do not have to make your columns the same size as mine.  Sort your output by size. It should look like this:

```
itemid size            maxprice discount              discounted price

----------- --------------- -------- ---------- ---------------------------
   1007 M                   5.00     1.5000                      3.5000
   1039 M                  10.00     3.0000                      7.0000
   1040 M                   7.00     2.1000                      4.9000
```

I ran into some problems with my homework. I know everything else is correct but line 5. I got an error
that said "Incorrect syntax near 'maxprice'." I was thinking it had something to do with implementing the calculation for discount on the previous line and putting that into line 5. That and this problem needs to have the ROUND statement. It feels really obvious. This is on Mimir by the way.

```
select itemid
     , size
     , maxprice
     , maxprice * .3 as [discount]
     , (maxprice * .3) as ROUND(maxprice - discount, 2) as [discounted price]
from item
where maxprice <= '10'
order by size;
```

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Please only tag a single RDBMS.

Comment: Title is still pretty generic even after the update. Syntax error? OK -- that could be pretty much anything and who will have a field named `maxprice`?

Comment: I'm not sure if mimir uses either of those

Answer (score 2):

You can only alias an expression once:

```
ROUND(maxprice - (maxprice * .3), 2) as [discounted price]
```

Or if the round needs to occur to the discount first (hard to tell with the sample data

```
maxprice - ROUND((maxprice * .3), 2) as [discounted price]
```

Also your filter

```
where maxprice <= '10'
```

Should really be comparing maxprice as a number to another number:

```
where maxprice <= 10
```

Comment: It's correct. I just need to isolate it so that only medium sizes show now.

Comment: Now that the command works, what have you tried? If it's homework, it's better that you think about it and give it a shot rather than someone else do it. Andrew has helped you with your first hurdle - give the second one a try.

Comment: That's what I'm doing. And thanks by the way.

Comment: By the way, the question (presumably given to you by teacher or teaching tool) is a bit bizarre: `show all clothing that is medium sized` then later `Sort your output by size`. As all rows will have 'M' as size, it's not really being sorted.

Comment: That is odd but hey, if that's how they want it written, I guess that's how it's got to be written then.